# TSQL matching the first instances of multiple values in a resultset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say I have part of a large query, as below, that returns a resultset with multiple rows of the same key information (PolNum) with different value information (PolPremium) in a random order.

Would it be possible to select the first matching PolNum fields and sum up the PolPremium. In this case I know that there are 2 PolNumber's used so given the screenshot of the resultset (yes I know it starts at 14 for illustration purposes) and return the first values and sum the result.

First match for PolNum 000035789547

(ROW 14) PolPremium - 32.00

First match for PolNum 000035789547

(ROW 16) PolPremium - 706043.00

Total summed should be 32.00 + 706043.00 = 706072.00

*Query*

```
    OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT PolNum, PolPremium
                FROM PN20 
                WHERE PolNum IN(SELECT PolNum FROM SvcPlanPolicyView
                                    WHERE SvcPlanPolicyView.ControlNum IN (SELECT val AS ServedCoverages FROM ufn_SplitMax(
                                                                            (SELECT TOP 1 ServicedCoverages FROM SV91 WHERE SV91.AccountKey = 3113413), ';')))
                ORDER BY PN20.PolEffDate DESC
        }
```

*Resultset*

[image]

Comment: For person who see this for first time it is just a pic and some sql statement. It is a picture of what? outer apply part or the final result? Add some test data and result that you want to see.

Comment: You can do this with ROW_NUMBER. You need to determine what you define as "first".

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I don't understand your comment. The test data is in the resultset image and the required result is detailed in the test with Result for line 1, Result for line 2 and Total. What is wrong with the description of the issue?

Comment: @SeanLange I am after the first matching row for each given PolNum field. Can you expand on how ROW_NUMBER might help me here?

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER in your outer apply to limit the return to only the "first" in each group. You have a couple of other code smells in there too. You have a subquery with a top 1 but there is no order by. Then there is table valued function. That may be a performance bottleneck depending on what that does.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the information, I will take a look at ROW_NUMBER. I will remove the Top 1 as it's no longer required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that pic if the final result your query produces. Then you can do something like:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      PolNum VARCHAR(20) ,
      PolPremium MONEY
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '000035789547', 32 ),
        ( '000035789547', 76 ),
        ( '000071709897', 706043.00 ),
        ( '000071709897', 1706043.00 )



SELECT  t.PolNum ,
        SUM(PolPremium) AS PolPremium
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PolNum ORDER BY PolPremium ) AS rn
          FROM      @t
        ) t
WHERE   rn = 1
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(t.PolNum, ( ))
```

Output:

```
PolNum          PolPremium
000035789547    32.00
000071709897    706043.00
NULL            706075.00
```

Just replace `@t` with your query. Also I assume that row with minimum of premium is the first. You could probably do filtering top row in outer apply part but it really not clear for me what is going on there without some sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to tweak it it meet my needs.